# Render 3D mesh to 2D SVG export

Tags: rendering, export

So I came across [this post](http://inkscapetutorials.org/2015/01/07/blender-adds-freestyle-svg-export-to-create-inkscape-editable-3d-lineart/) about a new [native method](https://developer.blender.org/D785) to render to SVG. That sounds great and all but how can it actually be done? Which buttons give me an SVG file at the end and where are they?

It seems pretty common for many blender/gimp plugins to simply not say how to use them. Even if the installation goes fine, there's no mechanism to find out what new buttons or menus exist.

Similar questions:

- [Can blender export 2D curves to svg?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6675/1713)
- [Is there a line render engine for Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8618/1713)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Non-native:

- http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?282824-SVG-output-script

  Install via `File->Preferences->Addons->Install From File...`

  Couldn't find any [menu additions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6677/1713) trying to add this to recent blender versions, but pretty sure I had it working in the past.
- https://github.com/hvfrancesco/freestylesvg

  Check Freestyle in the Render tab of the Properties window (bottom right). In the Render Layers tab, change `Frestyle->Control Mode` to `Python Scripting Mode` and load one of the scripts from the link. The blender file must be saved for this to work and then the SVG just appears in the output directory (or maybe the same dir as .blend, I've forgotten) after rendering.

### Native:

- https://developer.blender.org/D785

The latest blender in fedora 21 doesn't have this addon, it's pretty new. Rather than find a recent binary build I just compiled from the source. [Checking out the blender repository](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Process/Addons#Working_with_Git) also gets the addon scripts. The one in question is `release/scripts/addons/render_freestyle_svg.py`. Hopefully this'll make it into the stable releases soon.

This addon needs to be enabled via `File->Preferences->Addons` (search for and check "Render: Freestyle SVG Exporter"). With this enabled, an additional section appears below `Freestyle` called `Freestyle SVG Export` in the Render tab of Properties (bottom left). Check this, and next time you render, a file will simply appear in the output directory. By default the output directory is `/tmp/` and my render was `/tmp/0001.svg`.

[image]

Comment: The freestyle addon is included in the 2.73 source download and should be in all binary copies of 2.73

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/render/render_freestyle_svg.html

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to convert your mesh to a grease Pencil first and then export as SVG.

`Object -> Convert -> Grease Pencil`

Then

`File -> Export -> Grease Pencil as SVG`