# Remove extra points in export to SVG

Tags: export, freestyle, path

Following [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23661/render-3d-mesh-to-2d-svg-export), I exported a scene to an SVG format using the bundled add-on ("Render: Freestyle SVG Exporter").

However, when I did that I noticed that the resulting SVG has a bunch of unnecessary points, as shown below:

[image]

Is there a way to remove those extra points and only have one point at each corner? (Note that I only have the outer path selected.) I have Blender v2.74.

Comment: You could use inkscape's *simplify* operator (`Ctrl` `L` IIRC)

Comment: You could report this as a bug in the freestyle SVG exporter.

Comment: I'm thinking about doing that. I want to make sure that there isn't some setting that I'm missing, or if this is supposed to be the behavior.

Comment: Or you can add the Simplification Modifier in the freeStyle line Style Modifier Stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the Sampling modifier from the Geometry modifier stack.

This modifier adds extra stroke vertices at a regular interval.  This modifier is added by default because it is necessary in many stylization situations, e.g., when you want variable color, alpha transparency and/or line thickness along stroke, and when you want to add distortion to stroke geometry.  If you don't need the extra points, you can just remove the modifier.

Comment: How do I do this? I looked at the Modifiers section in the Properties pane and saw that no modifiers were added.

Comment: Go to the Render Layers properties window > Freestyle Line Style > Geometry, and you will find the Sampling modifier that needs to be removed.