# Simplify freestyle svg

Tags: export, freestyle, svg

I am trying to export this part to an svg and would like to keep the exported paths as simple as possible:

[image]

The result looks good at first

[image]

However, when viewed in Inkscape the results I get are short paths and lots of individual nodes (especially in the corner areas, e.g. on the top right - without clear edges).

[image]

I also removed the Sampling modifier from the Geometry modifier stack (mentioned [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31855/remove-extra-points-in-export-to-svg)) but it didn't help. Any other settings that yield simler shapes and less short paths (also fewer nodes)?

Comment: Blender export each Edge as an individual svg stroke. Maybe you'll get a cleaner result by using Path/Simplify (in Inkscape).

Comment: Thank you @thibsert I tried that already but it doesn't really help because these are individual paths that are really short - so there is not much to simplify unfortunately. The best solution I have so far is to use the bezier tool in inkscape and draw the lines by hand.